# Espresso, click on a spinner Item

Tags: java, android, android-espresso

I'm desperately trying to simulate a click on a spinner item with Espresso.

The spinner is populated with objects from the class Project. This class has a toString() method, which allows the spinner to display String.

```
private void populateDialogSpinner() {
        final ArrayAdapter<Project> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<Project>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, allProjects);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        vm.getAllProjects().observe(this, projects -> {
            allProjects.clear();
            allProjects.addAll(projects);
            adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
        });
```

I have found several solutions in order to use this spinner with Espresso but none of them has worked. This is my Test class.

```
    @Test
    public void addActivity () throws InterruptedException {
        onView(withId(R.id.fab_add_task)).perform(click()); 
        onView(withId(R.id.txt_task_name)).perform(replaceText(textTaskText), closeSoftKeyboard()); 
        onView(withId(R.id.project_spinner)).perform(click());

// A few solutions I have tried : 
// 1 onView(withText("Projet Lucidia")).perform(click());
// 2 onData(anything())
//       .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.project_spinner))
//       .onChildView(withMyValue("Projet L"))
//       .perform(click());
// 3 onData(anything()).atPosition(1).perform(click());
// 4 onView(allOf(withId(R.id.project_spinner), withSpinnerText("Project Lucidia"))).perform(click());
```

withMyValue refers to this class

```
public static Matcher<View> childAtPosition(final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int position) {

        return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
            @Override
            public void describeTo(Description description) {
                description.appendText("Child at position " + position + " in parent ");
                parentMatcher.describeTo(description);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
                ViewParent parent = view.getParent();
                return parent instanceof ViewGroup && parentMatcher.matches(parent) && view.equals(((ViewGroup) parent).getChildAt(position));
            }
        };
    }
```

Each time, the emulator stays with the spinner open like this :
[image: Emulator]

Any idea of how I can handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's the best answer but I have found this code thats works perfectly well.

```
UiDevice uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        UiObject spinnerItem = uiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("Projet Lucidia"));
        spinnerItem.click();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).